# Force order of tags

Tags: support, tags

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50125497/2640636), in which OP is looking for a `sed` solution, but would be ok with an `awk` one. The title of the question is

> How to reduce the number of delimiters using sed

The order in which the tags are displayed is

> awk, sed, delimiter-separated-values

Funnily, the html page title is thus

> awk - How to reduce the number of delimiters using sed

I tried editing the question, so that the `sed` tag appears before `awk`, but it reverted back. It seems that the order of tags is somehow automatically determined, and is not alphabetical, since the last tag's name starts with a *d*.

Is there a way to force the tag order, so that the html title begins with the proper tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tag is found in the title already, the html page title doesn't put it in again. So if you edit the title to include the word awk, it should get rid of the "awk -" in front.

Since the OP is okay with either Sed or Awk, you could edit the title to be:

> How to reduce the number of delimiters using sed or awk?

This won't change the tag order, but it will fix the html title.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited the question.

Comment: @SU3 I think this one is better :)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to select the tag used in the page title. It always uses the most popular (highest number of questions) of the given tags.

You could post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but I don't think there are     *that* many cases where such a feature would be useful.